# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in mpdf.php on line 11008

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mPDF in my web application.

I have to create invoice documents with the help of Mpdf..
So html table with large number of rows (ie: if it exists single page) rise this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in MPDF56/mpdf.php on
>   line 11008

I am using following code to generate pdf:

```
require_once(MPDF_PATH);
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','0','',2,2,2,2,1,1);
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/invoice_print.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$html .="";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output("$fileName",'D');
```

I have tried with/without arguments in constructor of Mpdf.
And I found mpdf works with first 4 params without any problem...

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','0','')
```

But when I add "margins" (ie: 5-8) params, will throws error described above.

Have anyone has a fix for this???

I have tried with mPDF 5.3 and 5.6

Comment: Did you check the manual? http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep... I got a fix from MPDF forum...

here is the link: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1109&page=1#Item_0

SOLUTION:
Just replace "**TableHeaderFooter**" function's first line from:

```
if(($horf=='H' || $horf=='F') && !empty($content)) {
```

to:

```
if(($horf=='H' || $horf=='F') && !empty($content) && !empty($content[0]) ) {
```

Hope this will help others...

Comment: The link is broken. Please specify in which file we should make the change.

Comment: Found it. The function is on mpdf.php file. Thanks for this solution. +1 rep

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with mPDF at the moment as well. What I discovered is that you're better off setting the margins like this:

```
$style = '<style>
@page *{
    margin-top: 2.54cm;
    margin-bottom: 2.54cm;
    margin-left: 3.175cm;
    margin-right: 3.175cm;
}
</style>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($style); //This writes the margin styles
$mpdf->WriteHTML($output); //This writes the html output
```

Comment: Thanks relentless.. But your solution was not worked... Still I got that same error.. :(

Comment: did you remove all the margin parameters from `$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','0','',2,2,2,2,1,1);`

Comment: replacing TableHeaderFooter first line with `if(($horf=='H' || $horf=='F') && !empty($content) && !empty($content[0]) ) {` fixed this. Thanks for your quick response relentless. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because you didn't set the `<thead>` and the
 `<tbody>` tags in the table inside your HTML.